# Select count complex in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'am noob in sql and I have a question for you. I need to create a count in sql, I tried by no result. So I have a table:

```
Event             Participant               Participant count
Test              123                        3
Test              123                        3
Test              456                        1
Test              123                        3
```

I need to create a count for participant: Participant 123 have 3 participations, Participant 456 have 1 participation. Help me please. Thx so much in advance

Comment: where is your attemted code?

Comment: Explain your problem, show us what you've tried... from what I see in your example, figures correspond to what you're expecting...

Comment: @Bartdude as this fella stated in question, he has no idea what to search for. so maybe abit to direct him what to search for is reasonable

Comment: I prefer investing time helping people knowing how to ask a question but please yourself :-) I could hardly point to any direction as I still don't understand the problem : he needs a count, and from where I see it he already has the proper figures in the last field of his table...

Answer (score 0):

What did you try? You need some kind of an aggregate function, using a group by statement.
E.g.

```
SELECT 
    participant,
    count(*) AS countofparticipations,
    sum(participantcount) AS sumofparticipations
FROM
    mytable
GROUP BY
    participant
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is "group by" in mysql

```
SELECT Participant,
       count(Participant_count)
FROM tblName
GROUP BY participant;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Participant,
       count(Participant_count) AS participant_count
FROM tblName
GROUP BY participant;
```